# Rotate object using Arduino - wrong results

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to rotate a cube around the Y-axis in Blender using a MPU6050 sensor. I am using Pyserial to send the rotation of the Y-axis from Arduino to Blender.

Inside the Serial Monitor I get pretty accurate results, but when I try to use that results to control a Cube in Blender, it rotates chaotically.

```
import serial

import time

import bpy

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbserial-14140','115200')

cube = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]

i=1
while i<500:

    degree = float(ser.readline())
    
    print(degree)
    cube.rotation_euler[1] = degree
    i+=1
    bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP',iterations=1)
```

If I comment the last line:

`#bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP',iterations=1)`

The data is displayed correctly in the command terminal

Comment: Chaotically sounds like Euler/degree mismatch. Maybe check that?

Comment: Exactly as Chris said. Arduino accelerometers do not give euler values but a vector direction. See this question for conversion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21622956/how-to-convert-direction-vector-to-euler-angles

Comment: The [MPU6050](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Datasheet1.pdf)  has an accelerometer that produces an acceleration vector and a gyroscope that produces rotation rates in degrees.  Assuming that you're using the Y axis rotation output, your problem is probably with the accuracy of the redraw timer.

Comment: Blender uses radians as a native rotation unit. If your data is in degrees, convert via  `math.radians(degree)`